# PHP Function 'overloops' array returns multiple instances of same object

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops

Newbie here, working on their second ever function. I've googles a bit on my problem, looked at PHP.net and at some articles on stack overflow, WC3schools, CoralCode, etc., but i haven't found anything that I can understand as of yet (i've done my diligence before come begging I promise).

The concept of my function is that it will take an array of whatever size, and print it out in rows of four. Function currently returns repeats itself overall equal to the size of the array. So if the array has 8 items, it returns nine groups (groupings defined visually by having the white line between them) of nine items. The first and the last have 16 boxes in them, 2-8 have 32 boxes in them where i was hoping to get back two rows of four with a while line between the two rows

see [here for visual error](http://max-o-matic.com/_test/template.php)
see [here for how it's meant to look](http://max-o-matic.com/template.php)

So to sum up, my loop is over iterating/returning too much/not returning the data in the way i hoped. I'm not sure how to phrase the question, but i've done my best to ask it as best I can.

```
function PrintFolio($aaPlaceholder)
    {
    //print out two rows of four from array with 8 items
    //if array had 7 items, then print row of 4 next row 3
    //if array had 16 items, print 4 rows of 4, etc.

    $height = sizeof($aaPlaceholder);//get size of array

    //loop through array of X items, for each group of 4 print as a row
    for($row = 0; $row < $height; $row++)    //looping through the rows

        {
            echo '<div class="row flush">'; //open div
            for($image = 0; $image < 4; $image++)    //each row is composed of 4 images
            {
                foreach($aaPlaceholder as $key => $value) {
                    printf(TEMPLATE_PORTFOLIO, $key, $value);
                    //replaced $template with constant TEMPLATE_PORTFOLIO!
                }
            }

            echo '</div>'; //end div group of 4
        }//end loop
    }//end function
```

If the answer is obvious, please remember i'm very new and it's not obvious to me or honestly I would not be asking.

Thank you for any help or guidance
cheers

Comment: Your inner `foreach` is going to print every item in `$aaPlaceholder`. This will happen every iteration of the inner `for` loop, which in turn happens every iteration of the outer `for` loop. So you're outputting the entire `$aaPlaceholder` far, far too many times.

Comment: in the inner foreach, you use again $aaPlaceholder; maybe you want $aaPlaceholder[$row].

Comment: Between the two `for` loops you are already looping over all of the items in your array. There should be no other looping construct. Of course there are more elegant solutions with just a single loop, but starting from this code you should first realize the inner `foreach` does nothing you 'd want to do.

Comment: I knew it was something, I'm repurposing some prior code to try to get it to do something 'more'. I will try adding the 'row' to see what happens, i'm in uncharted territory for me right now. Thank you folks.

Comment: I revised my foreach line as so 'foreach($aaPlaceholder[$row] as $key => $value) {' the result was two errors. 1.) Undefined offset: 0. 2.)  Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). The adding '[$row]' sounded like a good idea, but i foobared it i think.

Comment: That was very helpful Jon - i commented out the inner for loop, leaving only the first for loop and then the inner foreach loop. I've updated my [example](http://max-o-matic.com/_test/template.php). It's still not correct but it is much closer and for that i thank you.

Comment: Thinking more on what Jon said, i created a new variable, $limit. I added the line '$limit = $height % 4;' and now the results are as hoped for, i just have to figure out why the white line appears before the images instead of behind them. But this is solved, thank you for helping me puzzle this out folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the height is not the size of the array but it is a fourth of it. 
Second, the inner foreach, as already stated in the comments, should not be changed: it should be deleted. You are already looping through your elements, no need to do it once more.

```
function PrintFolio($aaPlaceholder)
{
//print out two rows of four from array with 8 items
//if array had 7 items, then print row of 4 next row 3
//if array had 16 items, print 4 rows of 4, etc.

$itemsCount = sizeof($aaPlaceholder);//get size of array 
$height = (int)ceil(sizeof($aaPlaceholder)/4);//get size of array divided by 4

//loop through array of X items, for each group of 4 print as a row
for($row = 0; $row < $height; $row++)    //looping through the rows

    {
        echo '<div class="row flush">'; //open div
        for($image = 0; $image < 4; $image++)    //each row is composed of 4 images
        {
             $aaPlaceholderIndex = $row*4+$image; //the index in the original array
             if( $aaPlaceholderIndex < $itemsCount ) {
                 printf(TEMPLATE_PORTFOLIO, $aaPlaceholderIndex, $aaPlaceholder[$aaPlaceholderIndex]);
            }
        }

        echo '</div>'; //end div group of 4
    }//end loop
}//end function
```

EDIT: this works if your array has plain numeric keys from 0 to n. Otherwise (e.g. associative array) it should read $aaPlaceholderIndex = array_keys($aaPlaceholder)[$row*4+$image];

EDIT AGAIN: so you use associative arrays (key are strings and not integers 0..n). I rushed a bit my edit about this. You'd better:

- define $keys =  array_keys($aaPlaceholder); outside the loops, where you define $height
- define $aaPlaceholderIndex = $keys[$row*4+$image];
- move this definition inside the "if" statement, which becomes

  ```
  if( $row*4+$image < $itemsCount )  {
      $aaPlaceholderIndex = $keys[$row*4+$image];
      printf(TEMPLATE_PORTFOLIO, $aaPlaceholderIndex, $aaPlaceholder[$aaPlaceholderIndex]);
  }
  ```

This way you run array_keys just once (good for performance) and you avoid a Notice "Undefined offset" when retrieving $keys[$row*4+$image] when $row*4+$image is too big.

Comment: Thank you dirLuca, I will explore your guidance. My array that i am calling currently reads like so ($aaGeneric['01.jpg'] = 'Assignment 01';) that is the first item in the array, the second time i change the 01s to 02s like so through all eight items in the array. So I am using string values for keys in my array not ints (hopefully i said that correctly)

Comment: Thank you dirluca, that was a really informative answer and I very much appreciate you help and guidance and I will be playing with this the rest of the day to dig all i can out of it. Thank you very much. Super helpful

Comment: I tested this some and found that I needed to edit the if statement from '<' to '<='. The last image was being sheered off/not printed/not returned because it was greater than the index count. But by setting the count of the index to '<=' it would get the final piece. Thank you for the help - I feel like I learned quite a bit today. I'm really looking forwards to when we get into function in my PHP class now. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. I edited it a bit more, I rushed a bit the non associative stuff. I'm a bit puzzled about the "<=" stuff. If you have, say, 7 images, then $itemsCount==7 and $row*4+$image should run from 0 (0*4+4) to 7 (1*4+3) and you want to print out all of them but one, so you need $row*4+$image to be strictly less then 7. Be sure you understand completely this point before feeling happy :-)

Comment: Thank you Dirluca, I am going over this again as i've no issue with returning to the well multiple times as water (wisdom) is best taken in in small, digestible bits ;) Thanks. I changed it to be form a '<' to to '<=' because the code was slicing off/not returning the last image. I believe that was because '<' is less then the number held in the array, verse being equal to or less than which gave me the final missing one; Experiment and now exploring what you've said - again thank you! Happy Valentines Day!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best answer, but this is what I figured out to do.

I created a new variable called 'limit' which is equal to the height var divided by four. I then commented out the second 'for loop' as it was causing problems, leaving only the first for loop and the foreach loop. This gave me back my array as hoped.

Revised code below:

```
function PrintFolio($aaPlaceholder)

    {
    //print out two rows of four from array with 8 items
    //if array had 7 items, then print row of 4 next row 3
    //if array had 16 items, print 4 rows of 4, etc.

    $height = sizeof($aaPlaceholder);//get size of array
    $limit = $height % 4;

    //loop through array of X items, for each group of 4 print as a row
    for($row = 0; $row <= $limit; $row++)    //looping through the rows

        {
            echo '<div class="row flush">'; //open div
            //for($image = 0; $image < 4; $image++)    //each row is composed of 4 images
            //{
                foreach($aaPlaceholder as $key => $value) {
                    printf(TEMPLATE_PORTFOLIO, $key, $value);
                    //replaced $template with constant TEMPLATE_PORTFOLIO!
                }
            //}

            echo '</div>'; //end div group of 4
        }//end loop
    }//end function
```